# Draw Model Using Multiple  VertexBuffers for position possibly

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vbo

(i decided to try to ask this question in a different way to possibly advance how to do this)

using listing 9-4 only as a basis  under "Best Practices for Working with Vertex Data" of Apples iOS guide for OpenGL ES, "OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS"

i want to basically "add" position date to this buffer.  (can it be done in some way?)

and then just call up which identifier when using glDrawElements...

is there a way to do this?  shown is example of what i want to do to give a visual.

```
    typedef struct VertexData3D
    {
        GLfloat position[3];
        GLfloat normal[3];
    } VertexData3D;

    GLuint    test1Buffer;
    GLuint    test2Buffer;
    GLuint    index1Buffer;
    GLuint    index2Buffer;

    const VertexData3D test1Buffer[] = {...};
    const VertexData3D test2Buffer[] = {...};
    const GLushort indices1[] = {...};
    const GLushort indices2[] = {...};

    void CreateBuffers()
    {
    // Static position data
        glGenBuffers(1, &test1Buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, test1Buffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(test1VertexData), test1VertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &test2Buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, test2Buffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(test2VertexData), test2VertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Static index data
        glGenBuffers(1, &index1Buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index1Buffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices1), indices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &index2Buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index2Buffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices2), indices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData3D), (void*)0);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(VertexData3D), (void*)12);
    }

// sometimes in the model,  draw out this test1model.
    void DrawModelusingTest1()
    {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, test1VertexData);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index1Buffer);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, theNumberInIndex1, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
    }

// sometimes in the model,  draw out this test2model.
   void DrawModelusingTest2()
    {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, test2VertexData);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index2Buffer);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, theNumberInIndex2, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would want [`glDrawElementsInstanced`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDrawElementsInstanced.xml)

Comment: i unfortunately left out in my description that this is for an iOS device.   I've corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Rotoglup's answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672748/opengl-basics-calling-gldrawelements-once-per-object) may help, specifically [this link](http://www.ozone3d.net/blogs/lab/20080316/opengl-geometry-instancing/) regarding instancing techniques.

I'd just add to the list of techniques the use of [glVertexAttribDivisor](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glVertexAttribDivisor.xml)
 to pass per instance (instead of per vertex) attributes, instead of using uniform buffers.

Basically, you use one VBO to hold the geometry and a second one to hold all the model-view matrices for each instance. You then use glVertexAttribDivisor to indicate that the model-view VBO should be advanced once per instance and call [glDrawElementsInstanced](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDrawElementsInstanced.xml) a single time to draw all your objects.

Comment: in my long description, i forgot to say that this is for an iOS device, i've corrected that.   this "use two VBO's" and glVertexAttribDivisor sounds interesting,  i have no idea how that would look,  but i'm doing research now to see if i can figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

First, your 3D mesh seems really static, there is no need to call glGenBuffers each and every frame. Do it once per mesh, at initialisation.

Your `for (int i = 0; i < numOfShapes; i++)` makes no sense to me. You bind tons of buffers, and call `glDrawElements` after the loop, which means that unless I'm missing something, only the last glBindBuffers actually do something.

If ALL your scene is static (only the camera moves), you can build a single, huge VBO (just like you did with glGenBuffers), put all your data in it, and call it 4 times with different matrices.

If anything is dynamic AND all your shapes are similar, look at instancing as Ben Voigt suggested; but simply avoiding to rebuild everything each frame should already boost your fps.

P.S I don't have the time to fully read your code, but if you only have ONE object repeated every time, I do hope you only have ONE vbo with multiple glDrawArrays calls to the same VBO...

Comment: the question i had was if my theory was correct?  it sounds like you are saying that particular loop isn't doing what i thought it would?  only the last glBindBuffer does anything,  does that mean that my whole premise is off?  or that just in that last part, i only need to call the bindbuffer once?   the idea is that these instances would have different rotations and position many times in their history,   i think that means yes, it is dynamic?. how would i go about doing this knowing that?    (i corrected the description to show this is for an iOS device)

Comment: I belive there is no instancing on iphone, so this way is blocked. Your objects move relative to each other, so a single VBO won't work either. Your last solution is to build a single VBO, and draw it multiple times. But do it well : create it once, and don't do useless glBind's.

Comment: i see... ouch,  so my theory is off (for iOS devices).